# Ansible can't recursively delete a directory

Tags: ansible

So, I am trying to recursively delete a directory with all files/folders inside.
I tried:

```
  - name: Cleaning up
    file:
      state: absent
      path: /tmp/myfolder/
```

But the directory did not get deleted. Is there any force/recursive parameter I can add? What am I missing?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this at all - were there any error messages? Are you sure you're targetting the correct host? Is the task "ok" or "changed"?

Comment: @BruceBecker The task is changed. I did install files from this directory before, so maybe there is still some process in the background that is not completed that prevents deleting the directory? But I did not get any error prompt.

Answer (score 1):

You may find the following format to be helpful:

```
- name: Recursively change ownership of a directory  
file:  
  path: /etc/foo
  state: directory
  recurse: yes
  owner: foo
  group: foo
```